# Run function with schedule is not working correctly

Tags: functions, cron

i´m trying to run a function with a schedule but the response is empty. I am developing a plugin where i will send a json encoded array to my IoT service. The service is fine. All other functions  are working fine. i want to send the update counts to my iot service.

What i have is this - my function:

```
    function send_count_updates_to_iobroker() { 
    
    $updates = wp_get_update_data();
    
    //Generate text if title is empty
    if ( empty($updates['title'] )) {
        $updatesTitle = "No updates available";
    } else {
        $updatesTitle = $updates['title'];
    }
    
    $datum_uhrzeit = datum_uhrzeit();

    $serviceURL = get_option( 'iob_iot_service_url_count_updates' );
    $data = wp_json_encode( (object) array( 
        'plugins'         => $updates['counts']['plugins'],
        'themes'          => $updates['counts']['themes'],
        'wordpress'       => $updates['counts']['wordpress'],
        'translations'    => $updates['counts']['translations'],
        'total'           => $updates['counts']['total'],
        'title'           => $updatesTitle,
        'timestamp'       => $datum_uhrzeit
    ), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES );
    
    $response = wp_remote_post( $serviceURL . $data );
    
    return $response; 
}
```

This function will be executed every five minutes with a schedule:

```
// own schedule five minutes
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'five_minute_cron_interval' );
function five_minute_cron_interval( $schedules ) { 
    $schedules['five_minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 300,
        'display'  => esc_html__( 'Alle 5 Minuten' ), );
    return $schedules;
}
```

I deactivated the wp-cron in wp-config.php and activate the serverside cron:

```
define( 'DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);

*/5 * * * * wget -q -O - https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron  >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The Cronjob is working - every five minutes it fires the events... But the response is always 0:

```
Aktualisiert:   05.10.2021 - 14:00:01 Uhr
Title:  No updates available
Plugins:    0
Themes: 0
Translations:   0
Core:   0
Total:  0
```

Also i used for tests the plugin Advanced Cron Manager where i can execute the events manually. This works fine. The response is:

```
Aktualisiert:   05.10.2021 - 14:01:00 Uhr
Title:  2 Plugin-Aktualisierungen
Plugins:    2
Themes: 0
Translations:   0
Core:   0
Total:  2
```

Can anyone tell me what i´m doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

nukleuz

**//Edit:**

Here is the missing code:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'jb_iobroker_iot_activation' );

add_action( 'jb_iobroker_iot_hourly_event', 'do_this_hourly' );
add_action( 'jb_iobroker_iot_5min_event', 'do_this_five_min_interval' );

 
function jb_iobroker_iot_activation() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'jb_iobroker_iot_hourly_event' );
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'five_minutes', 'jb_iobroker_iot_5min_event' );
}
 
function do_this_hourly() {
    checkPluginUpdates();
    send_bloginfo_to_iobroker();
}

function do_this_five_min_interval() {
    send_count_updates_to_iobroker();
}


register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'jb_iobroker_iot_deactivation' );
 
function jb_iobroker_iot_deactivation() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'jb_iobroker_iot_hourly_event' );
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'jb_iobroker_iot_5min_event' );
}

// own schedule five minutes
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'five_minute_cron_interval' );
function five_minute_cron_interval( $schedules ) { 
    $schedules['five_minutes'] = array(
        'interval' => 300,
        'display'  => esc_html__( 'Alle 5 Minuten' ), );
    return $schedules;
}
```

Comment: The response from where? Do you mean the response from `wp-cron.php` or the response from your IOT service? No cron jobs are registered in the code in your question, did you miss out parts?

Comment: I mean the response from iot service.

Comment: is the iot service not a 3rd party? Wouldn't the issue be in the iot service not WP?

Comment: No,, because other functions are working fine.

And this function in the question  is working when i execute the event in the Advanced Cron Manager Plugin. The plugin lists all the registered events/crons. Each of them have the option to execute manually - if i do that the data in the json is fine. All updateable plugins are shown.

But if the cronjob executes the function all values are zero/0...

So the iot-service is not the problem.

The iot service is just a url where i send the data/array as json in my homeautomation to visualize the information...

Comment: are you sure that the value is actually `0`? And not PHP trying to marshal `undefined` into a falsey value that resolves to `0`? `wp_get_update_data` is full of checks to test if the current user can do something, but cron jobs don't have a current user. Wouldn't it make more sense to hook into when these update checks happen and send the data on that hook instead?

Comment: additionally, a lot of the checks in that function don't actually check for updates, they just retrieve the transient from when it last happened and pull the data out if it's there, or return `0` if it isn't or the current user isn't allowed

Comment: look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_plugins/ which does the actual checking with .org for plugins/translations/locales, the function you're using doesn't make network requests

Comment: Yes, i´m sure that the values are 0. Here is the json i get:
{"plugins":0,"themes":0,"wordpress":0,"translations":0,"total":0,"title":"No updates available","timestamp":"06.10.2021 - 12:50:02 Uhr"}

Comment: Which hook could i use?

Comment: For tests i used the init-hook and it works!
Which hook could i use for it - i need it run only ones or twice a day?

Comment: it runs on `init` because you are logged in as a user that can check for updates. On cron jobs there is no user so the capability checks fail. Even then, `wp_get_update_data` does not check for updates, you're just re-sending the same cached data ( from a function that can't be used on cron jobs ). `wp_get_update_data` does not do what you think it does, did you look at `wp_update_plugins`?

Comment: you are right - it only works with logged-in user who has the permission.
i will take a look at wp_update_plugins()...

Comment: OK, i see - in the function: wp_update_plugins() are only plugins and if i´m right i have to use similar functions for core, themes etc. to count them... Right?

Comment: yes, there'll be equivalent functions that do similar things. The function you used just grabs the cached transient those functions generates

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation